# Blazor using double to set position of component use a comma instead of a dot ( 10,5% in stead of 10.5%)

Tags: blazor, globalization

When I set the position of a Blazor component, it send to the browser `10,5` instead of `10.5`. I guess that it should be done with invariant culture but I can't find where to add it.

```
style="position: relative ; top: @(_offsetY)%; left: @(_offsetX)%;"

private double _offsetX = 10.5;
private double _offsetY = 10.5;
```

Comment: I've tested this and am not seeing commas.  However, the value in the style is a string, so why not use `ToString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rendering of numbers and dates from text strings is culture sensitive, so if the browser has a non-english culture, e.g. DE-de (German) it will follow that convention.

Using `ToString()` as suggested will fix this.

```cs
@(_offsetY.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))%
```

You might want a helper function in the code to make this simpler, e.g.

```cs
  string Percentage(double value) => value.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) + "%";
```